# VBA InternetExplorer page loading error

Tags: excel, vba

When I run below code with F5 it is giving me an error message **"Object variable or with block variable not set"** on this line
**(Set DivClasses = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("srp_containerfl "))**, because page is not completely loading after clicking on the button, **(Do While IEObj.readyState <> 4 Or IEObj.Busy: DoEvents: Loop)** this line of code is not working properly, as it is going to next line before completely loading the page.

If I manually run this code and giving some time to load the page, it is running fine.

Sub Fetch_NaukriDotCom_Data()

```
Dim IEObj                   As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc                 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim divcl                   As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim DivClass                As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim DivClasses              As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim DataContainer           As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim DataContainerChild      As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim DataContainerChilds     As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim DataOneContainer        As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim DataOneContainers       As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim StrClassName            As String
Dim Int_i                   As Integer

Set IEObj = New InternetExplorer
IEObj.Visible = True
IEObj.navigate "https://www.naukri.com/"

With IEObj
    Do While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    .document.getElementsByName("qp").Item.innerText = "VBA Developer"
    .document.getElementsByName("ql").Item.innerText = "Noida"
    .document.getElementById("qsbFormBtn").Click
End With

Do While IEObj.readyState <> 4 Or IEObj.Busy: DoEvents: Loop 'This loop is not working properly, as it is going
                                                             'to next line, without completely loading the page

Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set HTMLDoc = IEObj.document
Set DivClasses = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("srp_container fl  ") 'Here Error occuring

Set DataContainerChilds = DivClasses.Item.Children
```

End Sub

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks
Kashif

Comment: maybe just `IEObj.navigate "https://www.naukri.com/vba-developer-jobs-in-noida"`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah IE acts funny sometimes and hence I use this

Replace

```
Do While IEObj.readyState <> 4 Or IEObj.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
```

with

```
Do While IEObj.readyState <> 4 Or IEObj.Busy: Wait 5 : Loop
```

And then paste this procedure at the end of the code. The `Wait 5` means wait for 5 seconds before checking the state again.

```
Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but still it is not working, when I run this code with F5 it is giving me an error on the line ( Set DataContainerChilds = DivClasses.Item.Children), and when I manually put cursor on the line ( Set DivClasses = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("srp_container fl ")) and run manually with F8, it is not giving me an error and running fine,

Why?

Please help me.

Kashif.